# urllib.request.urlopen cannot fetch the primaries page of Stack Overflow elections

Tags: python, python-3.4, urllib

I have a little [script](https://github.com/janosgyerik/soup-examples/blob/master/examples/se-primaries.py) to summarize and sort the candidate scores in Stack Exchange election primaries. It works for most sites, except for Stack Overflow, where retrieving the URL using `request.urlopen` of `urllib` fails with 403 error (Forbidden). To demonstrate the problem:

```
from urllib import request

urls = (
    'http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary',
)

for url in urls:
    print('fetching {} ...'.format(url))
    request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Output, the URLs of Math SE and Server Fault work fine, but Stack Overflow fails:

> ```
> fetching http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary ...
> fetching http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary ...
> fetching http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "examples/t.py", line 11, in <module>
>     request.urlopen(url).read()
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
>     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
>     response = meth(req, response)
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_response
>     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
>     return self._call_chain(*args)
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)
>   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
>     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
> ```

Using `curl`, all URLs work. So the problem seems to be specific to `request.urlopen` of `urllib`. I tried in OSX and Linux, same result. What's going on? How to explain this?

Comment: Confirmed your results on python3.4 on linux. Found that it works ok with requests on python2.7.

Comment: stackoverflow.com returns 403 to the user-agent used by urllib, others ok:    `curl -s -o /dev/null -A 'Python-urllib/3.4' http://stackoverflow.com -w "%{http_code}\n"`
*403*
`curl -s -o /dev/null -A 'python-urllib/3.4' http://stackoverflow.com -w "%{http_code}\n"`
*200*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the user-agent that gets sent with urllib. This code works for me:

```
from urllib import request

urls = (
    'http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary',
)

for url in urls:
    print('fetching {} ...'.format(url))
    try:
        request.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        print('got an exception, changing user-agent to urllib3 default')
        req = request.Request(url)
        req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Python-urllib/3.4')
        try:
            request.urlopen(req)
        except:
            print('got another exception, changing user-agent to something else')
            req.add_header('User-Agent', 'not-Python-urllib/3.4')
            request.urlopen(req)
```

And here's the current output (2015-11-16) with blank lines added for readability:

```
fetching http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary ...
success with url: http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary

fetching http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary ...
success with url: http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary

fetching http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary ...
got an exception, changing user-agent to urllib default
got another exception, changing user-agent to something else
success with url: http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary
```

Comment: @janos do you have any ideas about where would be the right place to ask the SO folks why they are rejecting this specific User-Agent? Thanks

Comment: I posted it on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310498/why-is-user-agent-python-urllib-rejected

Comment: Thanks for posting, I am following it over there now.

Answer (score 2):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#) instead of urllib

```
import requests

urls = (
    'http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary',
)

for url in urls:
    print('fetching {} ...'.format(url))
    data = requests.get(url)
```

and if you want to make it slightly more efficient by using a single HTTP session

```
import requests

urls = (
    'http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://serverfault.com/election/5?tab=primary',
    'http://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary',
)
with requests.Session() as session:
    for url in urls:
        print('fetching {} ...'.format(url))
        data = session.get(url)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Any idea what's wrong with `urllib` ?

Comment: I think I've figured it out - see my answer.

Comment: @janos, urllib is just messy to be honest. I always recommend going with requests when you can, the solutions are much cleaner and simple most of the time.

Comment: I agree - and that was the first thing I verified (see my original comment). The original question included this: *What's going on? How to explain this?* which I believe I've just answered - stackoverflow.com appears to be checking for certain `user-agent`s!